# Visual studio express 2013 web

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

sorry to bother you all but i have a simple problem i need help with:

1)Im building a website and i have this problem:
whenever i put design view on a .aspx page and change an image's size, it would cause all images on all the website to become the same size. It's really bothering me and i don't how to fix. Please help.

2)This is my home.aspx page, whenever i view in designer mode, it would show me full contents but whenever i run the page as in view browser, it shows blank. What is wrong with my code?

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"          CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="EliteHosting._Default" %>
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">      
    <h5><strong>99.9%</strong> Guaranteed Uptime</h5>
                    </div>
                          <div class="col-md-4">  
           <h5>Guaranteed Speed & Scalibility</h5>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4">  
                <h5>No Setup Fees</h5>
                                                      </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">  
                <h5><strong>30</strong> Days Money Back Guarantee</h5>
                                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-md-4">  
               <h5> 24/7 Customer Support</h5>
                                          </div>
                                                  <div class="col-md-4">  
                <h5>Arabic Supported Live Chat</h5>
                                                      </div>
                  </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

        <img src="Resources/webhosting.png" />
        <h2>Build Your Own Website</h2>
        <p>
            Do you wish to start a blog that your friends and family can view? Do you wish to   create a college project?
            Maybe you own a small local store and wish to list its products on the world wide web? Our shared website 
            hosting plan is the quickest and most affordable way to get your website online. </p>
         <p>You can now build your own website starting at $5/Month.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="/shared">Hosting Plans &raquo;</a>
        </p>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="Resources/hosting.png" />
        <h2>Virtual Private Servers</h2>
        <p>
            Now with solid virtual servers, you are able to develop, design and business more power,
            speed and stability to successfully run professional websites and applications. 
            If you need to host a website that is experiencing high traffic and requires maximum stability
            with maximum performance, then VPS hosting is just what you need.</p>
         <p>Gain access remotely to a virtual PC of your choice either Windows or Linux based hosted in our data centers.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="/virtual">VPS Plans &raquo;</a>
        </p>
    </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                 <img src="Resources/FREE_Hosting12.jpg" />
        <h2>Resellers</h2>
        <p>
            You have found the perfect place to help you start offering your own web hosting
            business without any server administration knowledge. You can create a hosting 
            account by just providing a domain, username and password. The account is 
            created as easy as it can get and your customers can start using their accounts
            to host their websites under your business name.
        </p>
         <p>Start your own business now and manage it directly from home!</p>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="/virtual">Reseller Plans &raquo;</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
  </asp:Content>
```

Comment: What's the code of rendered page?

Comment: @MarkZucchini do you mean the master page?

Comment: No. What's HTML content of compiled page.

Comment: @MarkZucchini im new to this, how can i access the html content of compiled page?

Comment: Run your website, then (when you see blank page) click right mouse button and select show source in browser

Answer (score 0):

1) Maybe you put all the images in the containers that takes their style from same css file. 
2) Maybe you didnt set the page as your start page? Maybe you made content invisible at the masterpage? You look a little newbie, I am not sure what advice to give you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have selected all the images. If you still didn't guess what is wrong than just go to editor and try to understand the code.

You better use Find and replace feature to modify only those images that you want to modify.